# How to capture https traffic

Tags: networking, android, traffic

I am trying to capture the requests of my android emulator. I want to know the data used by my android app. I tried various ways which didn't work. I am trying to do that using the emulator now. I have emulated my android device in ubuntu and I want to capture all traffic of my android emulator(http and https) using a tool.

We have fiddler in windows but this emulator stuff did not work there.

Answer (score 4):

Consider [wireshark](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wireshark)

```
sudo apt-get install wireshark
```

This should help you sniff out any traffic originating from your android emulator to http https based on a variety of filter criteria.

Comment: Can this capture HTTPS GET/POST sent/received data?

Comment: Yes - wireshark is quite powerful and it's probably looking at some of the tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`wireshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/) or command line tool `tshark`. [`tcpdump`](http://www.tcpdump.org/) is another option.

```
sudo apt-get install tcpdump
tcpdump -i $interface
```